# How to eliminate empty new line using Regex?

Tags: java, regex

how to eliminate empty new line into source code using regex.?

my basic is java

example :

```
class ex{
     String a="Hello World";

     public static void main(String[] args){
          System.out.println(a);

     }
}
```

result source code without empty new line :

```
class ex{
     String a="Hello World";
     public static void main(String[] args){
          System.out.println(a);
     }
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+empty+lines+from+file+java&oq=remove+empty+lines+from+file+java&aqs=chrome..69i57.4146j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: If you want to use some IDE to do the job you could just replace all `\n\n` (or `\r\n\r\n`) with `\n` (or `\r\n`). But don't you think that this might lower readability of your code?

Comment: There are many pretty-print source indenters that will do that. One such example is [artistic style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) (or `astyle`). Also, your code is illegal because you can't access an instance field `a` from a static method.

Comment: @Jan Legner : i do not use IDE, i using text editor

Comment: @Elliot Frisch : i'm sorry sir, i gave an example of a simple code.
i'm sorry, i was not examined.

Comment: Run your file through grep (Linux) or one of the freely available grep-work-alikes on Windows. Google "grep on windows". The command (shell or cmd) would be:  `grep -v '^\s*$' Input.java >Output.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete an empty line use:

```
String result = text.replaceAll("(?im)^\\s*\r?\n", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using:

```
//read line
if (line.matches("^\\s*$")) {
    System.out.println("ignoring empty line");
}
```

Alternatively, you could use IDE's like eclipse/netbeans/Intellij etc and configure how you would like to indent your code automatically.

Comment: By using IDE (code formatter with in IDE) else you will have to manually do stuff like checking file using code, writing all the non empty line into another temp file and then renaming file back to one you had.

Answer (score 0):

Many modifications of a text file (Java or otherwise) can be achieved by using standard tools. Writing a program for eliminating empty lines is a waste of time.

If you are on Linux, run your file through grep:

```
grep -v '^\s*$' Input.java >Output.java
```

For Windows, get one of the work-alikes which Google ("grep on windows") will find you. The command, using cmd, would be the same, but the Windows program may come with a GUI, which might make it even simpler.